# I have added a custom column in WP admin that shows posts ID, how can I set a link on each ID pointing to the corresponding post in order to view it?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I have added a custom column in WP admin that shows posts ID (and let have a search by code), how can I set a link on each ID pointing to the corresponding post in order to view it (not edit) ?

This is the code I used. Which elements have I to add in order to get the above mentioned links?

```
function add_column( $columns ){
    $columns['post_id_clmn'] = 'ID'; // $columns['Column ID'] = 'Column Title';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'add_column', 5);

function column_content( $column, $id ){
    if( $column === 'post_id_clmn')
        echo $id;
}
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'column_content', 5, 2);
/**
* Add search custom posts by their ID in WordPress dashboard
*
*/
add_action( 'parse_request', 'cdxn_search_by_id' );
function cdxn_search_by_id( $wp ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if( !is_admin() && 'edit.php' != $pagenow && 'post' !== $_GET['post_type']) {
        return;
    }
        
    // If it's not a search return
    if( !isset( $wp->query_vars['s'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
        
    // Validate the numeric value
    $id = absint( substr( $wp->query_vars['s'], 0 ) );
    if( !$id ) {
        return; 
    }

        
    unset( $wp->query_vars['s'] );
    $wp->query_vars['p'] = $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view it you just need to get the permalink, so this should work:

```
 function column_content( $column, $id ) {

    if( $column === 'post_id_clmn') {
        $link = get_the_permalink($id);
        echo "<a href='" . $link . "' target='_blank'>" . $id . "</a>";
    }
    
 }
```